# PHP foreach stop after first child is met

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

Please keep in ming all read a lot of "related" answer here and used Google a lot before coming to you.

It's my first hand at xml using PHP code.

Here is the xml file (test.xml) I'm looking at:

```
    <quizReport xmlns="http://empty.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://empty.com" version="1">
<quizSettings quizType="graded" maxScore="460" maxNormalizedScore="100" timeLimit="0"><passingPercent>0.6</passingPercent></quizSettings>
<summary score="142" percent="0.3087" time="192"><variables><variable name="USER_NAME" title="Nom" value="test1457"/><variable name="USER_EMAIL" title="Courriel" value="test@1457.com"/><variable name="DEPARTEMENT" title="Departement" value="Designers"/></variables></summary>
<questions>
<multipleChoiceQuestion id="{3BFC44A3-137B-496B-900D-E6908253C106}" status="correct" maxPoints="10" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="10" usedAttempts="1"><direction>Combien de temps cela prend-il, en moyenne, pour concevoir et produire une ouverture en 3D pour un bulletin d'actualités?
    </direction><answers correctAnswerIndex="2" userAnswerIndex="2"><answer>6 jours
    </answer><answer>24 jours
    </answer><answer>6 semaines
    </answer><answer>24 semaines
    </answer></answers></multipleChoiceQuestion>

    <multipleChoiceQuestion id="{2CEDBF79-0864-4E1A-954A-F7CA17989314}" status="correct" maxPoints="10" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="10" usedAttempts="1"><direction>Combien d'appels par heure sont traités par l'équipe du CCR et des moyens de production en période de pointe régulière (sans événements spéciaux)?
    </direction><answers correctAnswerIndex="2" userAnswerIndex="2"><answer>Environ 15 appels par heure
    </answer><answer>Environ 25 appels par heure
    </answer><answer>Environ 35 appels par heure
    </answer><answer>Environ 65 appels par heure
    </answer></answers></multipleChoiceQuestion>

    <multipleChoiceQuestion id="{71221928-8909-44BC-94B4-C0C011E297F7}" status="correct" maxPoints="10" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="10" usedAttempts="1"><direction>Avec qui les médiamans travaillent-ils de concert pour déterminer ce qui doit être conservé dans le système d'archivage?
    </direction><answers correctAnswerIndex="0" userAnswerIndex="0"><answer>Les médiathécaires
    </answer><answer>Les monteurs
    </answer><answer>Les directeurs techniques
    </answer><answer>Les chefs de pupitre
    </answer></answers></multipleChoiceQuestion>
    <multipleChoiceQuestion id="{C6CDB118-B4E0-4856-A7AB-69A35CEBBB44}" status="correct" maxPoints="10" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="10" usedAttempts="1"><direction>Quelle est la capacité du système de stockage robotisé sur lequel les médiamans envoient les archives du système Avid?
    </direction><answers correctAnswerIndex="3" userAnswerIndex="3"><answer>500 Gigaoctets
    </answer><answer>12 Téraoctects
    </answer><answer>500 Téraoctects
    </answer><answer>12 Pétaoctets
    </answer></answers></multipleChoiceQuestion>
</questions>
</quizReport>
```

And the PHP code :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->questions as $multipleChoiceQuestion) { 
    echo $multipleChoiceQuestion->multipleChoiceQuestion['id'];
    echo "<br>"; 
}
?>
```

My goal is to get all ID questions (to later put them in database)

The foreach seems to see only go through the first child of the xml document (on which I don't have any control on the structure) and stop. When I execute it, I only get the first question ID.

I'm expecting the following result :

```
{3BFC44A3-137B-496B-900D-E6908253C106}
{2CEDBF79-0864-4E1A-954A-F7CA17989314}
{71221928-8909-44BC-94B4-C0C011E297F7}
{C6CDB118-B4E0-4856-A7AB-69A35CEBBB44}
```

And I get :

```
{3BFC44A3-137B-496B-900D-E6908253C106}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You've got some copy/paste problems because this isn't [valid xml](http://xmlvalidation.com/). You're missing a closing `summary` tag. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better assist you.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason, a closing tag was missing.
I'va made en edit. The code provided now compare to the original I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($xml->questions as $multipleChoiceQuestion)
```

Because you only have one `question` node, then you're only going to get one iteration in a loop.

You're getting the first value because you actually dig in to that first node.

```
echo $multipleChoiceQuestion->multipleChoiceQuestion['id'];
```

So basically, just go two nodes deep for your loop, and then only level deep in the loop.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$xml=simplexml_load_file(__DIR__."/test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->questions->multipleChoiceQuestion as $multipleChoiceQuestion) { 
    echo $multipleChoiceQuestion['id'];
    echo "<br>"; 
}
```

This outputs:

> {3BFC44A3-137B-496B-900D-E6908253C106}
> {2CEDBF79-0864-4E1A-954A-F7CA17989314}
> {71221928-8909-44BC-94B4-C0C011E297F7}
> {C6CDB118-B4E0-4856-A7AB-69A35CEBBB44}

Comment: That did the trick! Solved!

I knoew it was something stupid... ;)